# Why is pluck('id') returning all id-s instead of just one?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

The following query returns every `Quote`'s id-s, instead of returning just one:

```
Quote::find(1)->pluck('id'); // --> [1, 2, 3, 4, ...]
```

Why is this happening?

### Update

Strangely, the query:

```
Quote::where('id', 1)->pluck('id'); // --> [1]
```

works as expected.

Comment: That is strange. Is your `Quote::find(1)` returning an `\App\Quote` or an `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` object?

Comment: @Jaw.sh it is returning a single `Quote` object

Comment: Yeah, that's properly bizarre. If you can reliably reduce it as a Laravel 5.2 error you should file a github report.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are (basically) two kinds of `pluck()` - one that works on collections, and one that works on `Builder` objects. When you do

```
Quote::where('id', 1)->pluck('id');
```

then you have a `Builder` object, since prior to the plucking you haven't returned anything from the database - you're still building the query. So that works, because the plucking is added to the query and executed.

However, when you do `Quote::find(1)`, you get a `Quote` object back - which is neither a `Builder` nor a `Collection`. Instead, Laravel creates a new query where it tries to pluck values from the database for you, based on which model you're on. In this case, that's the `Quote`.

This behaviour was changed in 5.2, so in 5.1 you'd get just the column value back - `1` in your case, as expected. But `pluck()` is taking over what used to be called `lists()` in earlier versions of Laravel, starting from 5.2. So your results are correct - however confusing.

Comment: I like your explanation on 5.2 vs 5.1. +1

Comment: Thank you @patricus. I thought our answers complemented each other nicely. :)

Comment: Both of your answers are great! Thank you

Comment: `value()` is the new `pluck()`, `pluck()` is now an alias for `lists()`

Comment: Exactly. Thank you for the addition.

Answer (score 4):

`Quote::find(1)` is returning a Quote object, not a Collection of Quotes. You are then calling `pluck('id')` on that quote object. Since the Quote object doesn't actually have a `pluck()` method, what this is actually doing is creating a new query builder instance for quotes, and calling pluck on that. It is the same as if you did `Quote::pluck('id')`. That is why you are getting all of the ids.

Since `Quote::find(1)` is going to return the Quote object, you don't need to call `pluck()` on it. You can just access the property.

```
$quote = Quote::find(1);
echo $quote->id;
```